# Ninja build failing while building lineageos 17.1

Tags: android, build, compiler-errors, custom-rom, lineageos

This is the error that is shown:

FAILED: ninja: 'out/soong/.intermediates/system/core/init/libinit/android_arm_armv8-a_core_static/gen/proto/system/core/init/persistent_properties.pb.h', needed by 'out/soong/.intermediates/system/core/init/init_second_stage/android_arm_armv8-a_core/obj/system/core/init/main.o', missing and no known rule to make it
ninja failed with: exit status 1

I am trying to use my own device tree and I think the problem is likely that. But I cannot figure out what exactly is the problem.

This is my device tree: https://github.com/harishnkr/android_device_samsung_j5xnlte
This is my local manifests file:  https://github.com/harishnkr/j5xnlte_local_manifest/blob/lineage-17.1/roomservice.xml

This is the manifest file I am using earlier and the one I as my source to build my own tree. It works perfectly: https://github.com/Galaxy-MSM8916/local_manifests/blob/master/lineage-17.1.xml

Thanks in advance.